# How to remove empty double quotes using java

Tags: java

Suppose that there is an unwanted double quotes inside a line, for example:`Ra""ja`.

I want to replace these quotes by this: `Ra"ja`.

My code:

```
name.replace("\"\"","\"");
```

but it doesn't work.

Any idea to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Works good for me. Maybe what you have are not double quotes at all. Perhaps it's 4 single quotes like this: '''' and here are 2 double quotes: "". With a lot of fonts, 4 single quote can look like 2 double-quotes